# Replace specific text only in specific fields using nawk

Tags: awk

My input data file abc.txt has this

```
"20131008","0004","0568","98"
```

I ran this command to replace the text

```
nawk -F, -vOFS=',' '{gsub("0568","0808",$3); print }' abc.txt
```

In the output the delimiter "," is replaced with a space. The output looks like this.

```
 "20131008" "0004" "0568" "98".
```

Can someone please help with this? I tried to replace the `-vOFS` but doesn't work.

Comment: What is your OS and `nawk` version?

Comment: This is because you use `-vOFS=','`. You need a space between `-v` and `OFS=','`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer demonstrate `awk` and `sed` examples, both in command line output and in file changes.

For `awk`, we'll use `$ awk -F"," '{gsub("0568", "0808", $3)}1' input.txt` and receive the changed string in command line output (or to variable), but the original file will not change.

```
$ cat input.txt 
"20131008","0004","0568","98"
$ awk -F"," '{gsub("0568", "0808", $3)}1' input.txt
"20131008" "0004" "0808" "98"
```

For `sed`, we'll use simple form `sed -i 's/string to replace/new string/g' input.txt` where `-i` flag is for changes in place (i.e. modifying the original file).

```
$ cat input.txt 
"20131008","0004","0568","98"
$ sed -i 's/0568/0808/g' input.txt
$ cat input.txt 
"20131008","0004","0808","98"
```

Although it's not what you asked for in `nawk` (I don't have it installed), I hope you'll find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have `nawk` but this works for me (with `gawk`, using the `--posix` switch):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{sub(/0568/,"0808",$3)}1' file
```

[fedorqui's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150883/replace-specific-text-only-in-specific-fields-using-nawk#comment245707_150883) suggests that you may need to use `-v OFS=','` rather than `-vOFS=','` but if input and output separator are the same, the assignment in the `BEGIN` block isn't much longer. I've also changed your `gsub` to `sub` as it looks like you're only looking to make one substitution. The first argument to either function is a regular expression so you shouldn't pass it a string.

Output:

```
"20131008","0004","0808","98"
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried this:

```
nawk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } { sub("0568","0808",$3) }1' abc.txt
```

It works fine.